# Getting request body of mock service worker and react testing library

Tags: reactjs, msw

So i am writing tests for one of my react projects and i just decided to use mock service worker to mock my api calls and i am trying to mock a login endpoint.So i am trying to simulate a login error where i return an error message when the input does not match a particular email. Given the code below;

```
const server = setupServer(
  rest.post("https://testlogin.com/api/v1/login", (req, res, ctx) => {
    // the issue is getting the email from the request body something like the code just below
    if (req.body["email"] != "test@example.com") {
      ctx.status(401);
      return res(
        ctx.json({
          success: false
        })
      );
    }
  })
);
```

How can i do that? Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Edit: MSW 2.0

Since the release of [MSW 2.0](https://mswjs.io/blog/introducing-msw-2.0), the way you operate with request/response bodies is the same now as you do with Fetch API.

```js
import { http, HttpResponse } from 'msw'
import { setupServer } from 'msw/node'

setupServer(
  http.post('/endpoint', async ({ request }) => {
    const data = await request.formData()
    const email = data.get('email')
  
    if (email !== 'test@example.com') {
      return HttpResponse.json({ success: false }, { status: 401 })
    }

    return HttpResponse.json({ success: true })
  })
)
```

> In this example, I read the request body as `FormData`. You can also read it as `.json()`, `.text()`, etc.—those are the regular `Request` instance methods.

Learn more about [the new version of MSW](https://mswjs.io/docs) and also [How to migrate from 1.x to 2.x](https://mswjs.io/docs/migrations/1.x-to-2.x).

### MSW 1.0

You should be able to get the `req.body.email` value *given your request sets the `Content-Type: application/json` header*. Without the Content-Type header, neither MSW nor your actual server could know what kind of data you're attempting to send (if anything, it can be a binary!). By providing the correct Content-Type header you form a correct request but also let MSW be sure that `req.body` should be parsed to an object.

```js
// your-code.js
fetch('https://testlogin.com/api/v1/login', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    // Adding this header is important so that "req.body"
    // is parsed into an object in your request handler.
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ login: 'admin@site.com' })
})
```

```js
// your-handlers.js
rest.post('https://testlogin.com/api/v1/login', (req, res, ctx) => {
  const { login } = req.body

  if (login !== 'test@example.com') {
    return res(ctx.status(401), ctx.json({ success: false }))
  }

  return res(ctx.json({ success: true }))
})
```

> Note how the `ctx.status(401)` call is *inside* the `res()` function call. Calling any `ctx[abc]` methods outside of `res` will result in no effect as they rely on being wrapped in `res`.

Comment: `req.body()` is now deprecated, if your body has JSON data you can use `req.json()` ([docs](https://mswjs.io/docs/api/request))

Comment: the body looks empty for me and I added the Content-Type